# Issues with Western Digital Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My System:

El Capitan 10.11.5

Mid-2012 Retina MBP

Processor: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7

Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

The Drive in Question:
https://www.cnet.com/products/wd-elements-desktop-wdbaau0020hbk-hard-drive-2-tb-usb-2-0-series/specs/

The issue:
There are two partitions on the drive that I use. When I plug in the drive I get the following error message:

> MacOSX Can't repair the disk "Mac"
>   You can still open or copy files on the disk, but you can’t save changes >to files on the disk. Back up the disk and reformat it as soon as you can.

When I look at terminal diskutil list I get the following:

[image: Terminal Output]

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:             Apple_Driver43                         28.7 KB    disk2s2
   3:             Apple_Driver43                         28.7 KB    disk2s3
   4:           Apple_Driver_ATA                         28.7 KB    disk2s4
   5:           Apple_Driver_ATA                         28.7 KB    disk2s5
   6:             Apple_FWDriver                         262.1 KB   disk2s6
   7:         Apple_Driver_IOKit                         262.1 KB   disk2s7
   8:              Apple_Patches                         262.1 KB   disk2s8
   9:                  Apple_HFS Mac                     1.0 TB     disk2s10
  10:                  Apple_HFS Windows                 1.0 TB     disk2s12
```

When I try to repair the disk I get an error that says "Error (or exit? can't quite remember) code is 8."

The other partition, "Windows" allows me to access the files without issue. However, the "Mac" partition simply displays as blank. Additionally, Disk Utility shows me that I have 8.6gb of photos, 300gb of movies, etc. which lends me to believe that the drive knows what's on it but I can't seem to access it.

TLDR, one partition of drive works, other displays as blank. DiskUtility tells me that it knows how much and of what there is on the disk.

Comment: Please don't post text as picture. I can't quickly copy/paste or Google search text from a pic. This is a long-time-no-see/when-I-was-young partition scheme from the 90ties (IIRC Mac OS 9 compatible). Who formatted the drive?

Comment: Sorry the formatting got all wonky when I copy and pasted it, I've only used this drive on Mac OSX devices so I have no idea why it would be OS 9 compatible. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I've edited my post with the text output.